# Is there a java parser can simulate mysql server parser?

Tags: java, mysql, parsing

I write a database mid-ware for mysql. I need to determine a sql statement isRead statement or isWrite statement and extract the schema and tables information. Some parser I found through google only parse the DML statement. But I need a parser can parse all statement what mysql server can do.

Do you think that is a good idea I call the mysql parser directly in java or is that possible?

Comment: Google search put your question on the top ; the next choice is http://sqlparser.com/

Comment: it is powerful, but I think it is not free.

Comment: True. BTW, I added java tag.  Hope that is fine.

Comment: SQL has a relatively small grammar. If you can find one online, or write it out yourself (or just the parts that matter to you), you could use a Parser generator. I'd recommend Coco/R (http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/coco/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you think that is a good idea I call the mysql parser directly in java or is that possible?

No I don't think it is a good idea.  Calling C / C++ code from Java is rarely a good idea.  And in this case, the parser is embedded in a whole bunch of other code, and it is *likely* to be able separate it out.  On top of that, it will emit the parse tree as complicated native data structures that will be difficult to use from Java.

A better approach would be to take an existing open source Java parser for SQL, and (over time) add support for parsing MySQL-specific statements.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using code from Alibaba's [Druid project](https://github.com/alibaba/druid). Although designed as a sophisticated connection pooling library, this project supports a very advanced [parser and AST](https://github.com/alibaba/druid/tree/master/src/main/java/com/alibaba/druid/sql) for ANSI SQL and non-ANSI dialects such as MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc. The project is open source and bears the very liberal Apache License Version 2.0.

The main entry points into this part of the library is [SQLUtils.java](https://github.com/alibaba/druid/blob/master/src/main/java/com/alibaba/druid/sql/SQLUtils.java).